# How to provide default url for mvcSiteMapNodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dry, mvcsitemapprovider

I have some nodes that are strictly navigation. So far I've handled this by using a "navigation node" route and explicitly setting the url (`~/Home/*`)on the nav only nodes. It works fine. This allows me to have a menu hierarchy without having to add dummy for each nav only menu item (which would be dumb) while allowing them to show up in the menu and breadcrumb hierarchy.

**Mvc.sitemap**

```xml
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" >
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Products" url="~/Home/Products"   roles="*">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Shampoo MAX" url="~/Home/Products/ShampooMAX" >
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Policies" controller="Object" action="List" type="Policy" >
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Quotes"  controller="Object" action="List" >
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Claims"  controller="Object" action="List">
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Documents" controller="Document" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Forms" controller="Form" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Links" url="~/Home/Links" roles="*">
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="https://interfarina.com/login#login" targetFrame="_blank"   title="Quoting" roles="*"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="https://drive.google.com/file/d/asdfsdfsdfsdfs/view" targetFrame="_blank"   title="Downloadable App" roles="*"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="https://gumbysafety.com/app/user/login" targetFrame="_blank"   title="Sales Tools" roles="*"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```cs
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Navigation-Only Node",
      url: "Home/{*url}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
  );
```

I'd like to clean up my `Mvc.sitemap` file a bit by removing all the urls from the navigation only nodes and trapping some event or overriding some method wherein I can generate the url for the node. The urls for these nodes as you can see can be generated from ancestor and self titles.

I'm not sure if the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki) is addressing this ability.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "navigation only node". All nodes are for navigation.

Comment: @NightOwl888, sorry. I mean, a node that has no controller or action. All it ends up doing is shifting where you are in the node path. The analogy would be a nested menu, where some menu items are there just to group other menus or commands, and then the leaf nodes actually execute a command. Same concept here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nodes in your menu that only exist on the client side, then you should not put them into the `SiteMap` at all. The `SiteMap` is sort of like a hierarchial database - you shouldn't put any UI logic in the database.

Instead, you should edit the display templates (or create different templates for different scenarios) in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder. The purpose of these templates is so you can control the HTML that is output by the HTML helpers.

You may need to add a [custom attribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node) or two in order to turn on and off specific parts of your display logic, but that can be done among the "real" (server side) navigation locations in your `SiteMap`.

Comment: I'm going to try this as time provides. I'm in a time crunch and what I have now is working but I agree with no UI in the database. I just never thought of the `Mvc.sitemap` as database; I thought it was a UI artifact kinda like the `web.config`.